# SQL Server GROUP BY troubles!

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting a frustrating error in one of my SQL Server 2008 queries. It parses fine, but crashes when I try to execute. The error I get is the following:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Column
>   'customertraffic_return.company' is
>   invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ctr.sp_id                     AS spid,
           Substring(ctr.company, 1, 20) AS company,
           cci.email_address             AS tech_email,
           CASE
             WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 'unknown'
             ELSE rating
           END                           AS rating
    FROM   customer_contactinfo cci
           INNER JOIN customertraffic_return ctr
             ON ctr.sp_id = cci.sp_id
    WHERE  cci.email_address <> ''
           AND cci.email_address NOT LIKE '%hotmail%'
           AND cci.email_address IS NOT NULL
           AND ( region LIKE 'Europe%'
                  OR region LIKE 'Asia%' )
           AND SERVICE IN ( '1', '2' )
           AND ( rating IN ( 'Premiere', 'Standard', 'unknown' )
                  OR rating IS NULL )
           AND msgcount >= 5000
    GROUP  BY ctr.sp_id,
              cci.email_address) AS a
WHERE  spid NOT IN (SELECT spid
                FROM   customer_exclude)
GROUP  BY spid,
      tech_email
```

Comment: Erm. What do you actually want this code to do? What's your expected output?

Comment: Well, if I remove the two GROUP BY statements, the query runs and returns a large dataset with the columns "spid" "company" "tech_email" and "Rating". This is what is expected, Group By is used to remove duplicates I believe. (New to SQL and I'm working wiht someone elses query)

Comment: GROUP BY groups the data - it doesn't just "remove duplicates". So what exactly are you trying to do so?? GROUP BY is typically used with aggregates like SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX etc. - you don't seem to have any of that, really.....

Comment: Well, if you just want to eliminate duplicates, use SELECT DISTINCT, and don't do all that unnecessary grouping. As @marc_s suggests, GROUP BY is usually used with aggregate functions. On the other hand, if you're using DISTINCT a lot, it's generally a sign that you've got your database design wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the error is pretty clear, no??

You're selecting those columns in your inner SELECT:

- spid
- company
- tech_email
- rating

and your grouping only by two of those (`GROUP BY ctr.sp_id, cci.email_address`).

Either you need group by all four of them (`GROUP BY ctr.sp_id, cci.email_address, company, rating`), or you need to apply an aggregate function (SUM, AVG, MIN, MAX) to the other two columns (`company` and `rating`).

Or maybe using a GROUP BY here is totally the wrong way to do - what is it you're really trying to do here??

Comment: Thanks Marc, you can see my reply to Matt Gibson above to see what it is I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Lucas311: ok, so if you remove the GROUP BY, you get way too many rows - which ones of those do you really want? Based on what criteria do you want to order / filter your data?? Do you want the top 5 entries for each "company", order by "rating" (largest first) ?? Or what are you looking for - still not clear what the **expected** result is...

Answer (score 2):

The inner query:

```
    SELECT ctr.sp_id                     AS spid,
           Substring(ctr.company, 1, 20) AS company,
           cci.email_address             AS tech_email,
           CASE
             WHEN rating IS NULL THEN 'unknown'
             ELSE rating
           END                           AS rating
    FROM   customer_contactinfo cci
           INNER JOIN customertraffic_return ctr
             ON ctr.sp_id = cci.sp_id
    WHERE  cci.email_address <> ''
           AND cci.email_address NOT LIKE '%hotmail%'
           AND cci.email_address IS NOT NULL
           AND ( region LIKE 'Europe%'
                  OR region LIKE 'Asia%' )
           AND SERVICE IN ( '1', '2' )
           AND ( rating IN ( 'Premiere', 'Standard', 'unknown' )
                  OR rating IS NULL )
           AND msgcount >= 5000
    GROUP  BY ctr.sp_id,
              cci.email_address
```

has 4 non-aggregate things in the select (`sp_id`, `company`, `email_address`, `rating`) and you only group on two of them, so it is throwing an error on the first one it sees

So you either need to not group by any of them or group by all of them

Comment: Thanks Daniel! Is it normal that this query would work in MySQL? Because I have the database in both MySQL and SQL Server versions and the query runs fin in MySQL.

Comment: The only thing I can think of that might make it work is that MySQL is inferring that since there are no aggregations in this inner query that `GROUP` ing is useless.

Comment: @Lucas: MySQL has a special 'feature' (!) whereby you don't have to include all the columns being selected in the GROUP BY clause. This is non-standard SQL, and the only engine with this 'feature'.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest replacing the * with a fully specified column list.

Comment: I just tried this and altough it's better, it didn't fix the original error.

SELECT spid, company, tech_email, rating
FROM ....

Comment: While I agree that `SELECT *` shouldn't be used in production code ever, that alone will not fix the problem....

Answer (score 1):

you can either group by all selected columns or use the other columns (not in group by clause) in a aggregate function (like sum)

you cannot: `select a,b,c from bla group by a,b`
but you can: `select a,b,sum(c) from bla groupy by a,b`